# Python Pydantic Callable with default function argument

Tags: python, function, python-typing, callable, pydantic

I have a function that returns another function. Example:

```
from typing import Callable, Optional

def create_object() -> Callable[[str, Optional[int]], str]:
   def create(name: str, length: int = 10) -> str:
      return # do something
   return create
```

How do I need to define Callable for length parameter with a default value?
If I will try to call this function only with name ( create_object()('Name') ) PyCharm will highlight it with warning what length argument is missing

Comment: can you provide the imports come with your code here?

Comment: @manaclan 

from typing import Callable, Optional

Comment: "Optional" doesn't mean the argument is optional, it means the argument is optional and the default value is None. The docs say: "Note that this is not the same concept as an optional argument, which is one that has a default."

Answer (score 0):

You should install pydantic pycharm plugin: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/pycharm_plugin/